# How can i connect remote sql server by Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

I have no enough experience on database systems. I have to connect to remote sql server and process some queries on it. How can i connect remote server by Entity Framework ?

Comment: I am just newbie on it. I don't know this thing happen by connection strings or not. While working on Entity Framework i have never seen even connection string. So i wanted to learn basic steps for it.

Comment: http://www.connectionstrings.com/ Read and Learn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Check if remote sql server is allowed remote connetions

2) In Visual Studio use Entity Framework wizard (add new connection)

Answer (score 2):

Same as you would with any other database connection tool: Make sure the server and all firewalls/proxy servers between you and the server accepts the connection, and then supply EF with a correct connection string.

However, if you're only going to process some sql queries, I would suggest using SQL Server Management Studio instead. Entity Framework is an ORM, not a database management tool.

Answer (score 1):

Here how I connect programmatically (no xml/appconfig file) to a remote server:

1. First check that your remote server is correctly parametrised. In particular one port has to be open. See this [MSDN post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/walzenbach/2010/04/14/how-to-enable-remote-connections-in-sql-server-2008/) for details.
2. Create the connection string as follow  (see [SqlConnectionStringBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx)):

   ```
   public static string GetRemoteConnectionString()
   {
       SqlConnectionStringBuilder sqlString = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder()
       {
         DataSource = $"{IP},{PORT}", // ex : 37.59.110.55,1433 
         InitialCatalog = "MyDatabaseName",  //Database
         IntegratedSecurity = false,
         MultipleActiveResultSets = true,
         ApplicationName = "EntityFramework",
         UserID = "MyUserId",
         Password = "MyPassword"
       };
       return sqlString.ToString();
   }
   ```
3. Then connect via the DbContext :

   ```
   public class MDBContext : DbContext
   {    
     public MDBContext () : base(GetRemoteConnectionString())
     {
     }
     ......
   }
   ```

Extra :

- You can also easily check connection (before to create the DbContext) as follow :

  ```
         try
         {
              using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(GetRemoteConnectionString()))
              {
                  con.Open();
              }
              success = true;
          }
          catch (Exception ex)
          {
             success = false;
              ...
          }
  ```